# Ошибка в простом тестовом виджете

Tags: виджет, android

Только начинаю писать под `android`, решил написать простой виджет который будет выводить некоторую информацию на экран в `textview`, изначально для вывода задаю константу с дальнейшим расчетом заменить ее (когда все будет работать) на значение получаемое из другого метода. Пытаюсь ссылаться на элемент в виджете при помощи метода `getViewByID` но пишет ошибку, так же и на `setContentView`. Как это нужно сделать правильно?

```
package ru.startandroid.develop.p1171simplewidget;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

  final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

  @Override
  public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onEnabled");
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onUpdate " + Arrays.toString(appWidgetIds));

    int s = 100500;
    ((Activity)context).setContentView(R.layout.widget);
    //TextView c = (TextView)findViewById(R.string.widget_text);
    //c.setText(Integer.toString(s)); 
     remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.string.widget_text, (Integer.toString(s)));
    //на remoteViews пишет - remoteViews cannot be resolved
  }

  @Override
  public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDeleted " + Arrays.toString(appWidgetIds));
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDisabled");
  }

}
```

Comment: А что за ошибка?

Comment: The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type MyWidget

Comment: автоматическое добавление импортовне помогло, если оно правильно работает конечно

Comment: вторая такая же: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type MyWidget, как вариант, может там по другому значение надо передавать хз... но тогда как...

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае наверное надо плясать от `Context context` что то типа:

```
((Activity)context).setContentView(...)
```

У MyWidget действительно нету таких методов :-)

Comment: спасибо,  буду теперь туда копать )

Comment: добавил строку ((Activity)context).setContentView(R.layout.widget) ошибку на ней не выдает, но сослаться на текст в объекте методом TextView c = (TextView)findViewById(R.string.widget_text) не получается, на TextView пишет - TextView cannot be resolved to a type, на findViewById пишет - The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type MyWidget, попробовал этот метод т. к. перед этим был setContentView(), видимо так тоже нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно работать через RemoteViews

```
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.yourID, "Some text");
```

Comment: попробовал так тоже, видимо надо еще его как то оформлять, remoteViews должен как то еще устанавливаться или связываться с чем то?

Comment: Вот что вам нужно сделать

        ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), 
        WidgetProvider.class.getName());

        int[] appWidgetIds = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.yourID, "Some text");
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);